# Make Folders in Apache Case Insensitive using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, case-insensitive

I need to make accessing directories on my server case insensitive.

How do I do that using htaccess?

Answer (score 3):

You have to install and enable the mod_speling module in apache and set the CheckCaseOnly Directive to On in your .htaccess

```
CheckCaseOnly On
```

Comment: ironic.

agent0074, is mod_spelling not enabled by default? I have a shared hosting account, so I don't have access to changing Apache modules.

Comment: @ycx: Looks like it is disabled by default. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html

Comment: It's really called "mod_speling" http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html
If it's enabled by default depends on your shared hosting provider, but don't think so, because it slows the server down a bit.

Comment: I can't enable mod_speling.

Is there not a Regex logic I can use?

Answer (score 2):

If you want requested URLs to be valid whether uppercase or lowercase letters are used, use mod_speling to make URLs case-insensitive. Write the following code in .htaccess file:

```
CheckSpelling On
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used because my hosting is shared and does not include the mod_spelling module but does support .htaccess, but this only works for one folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^student-government/$ http://www.tombarrasso.com/Student-Government/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

The folder to redirect to can be any case, so you could use lower-case folders and redirect all variations of spelling there.

I suppose it could be adapted with a little bit of REGEX to work for all folders rather than just one. This worked for me on Apache 2.2.14 (Unix).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution-1:** To make case-insensitive directory and files names with respect to the requested URL we can add the following two lines to the app's .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    #Once enabled, mod_speling redirects misspelled requests to any nearest matching resources. Uses a bit of memory, but can be useful if you've been changing URIs or have lots of similarly named URIs:
    CheckSpelling On
    CheckCaseOnly on
</IfModule>
```

**Solution-2:**
Again if we want just a few predefined directories to go to specific directories, then apply the below lines instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^my-dir/old-dir-1/$ /my-dir/new-dir-1/ [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteRule ^my-dir/old-dir-2/$ /my-dir/new-dir-2/ [R=301,L,NE]
    RewriteRule ^my-dir/old-dir-3/$ /my-dir/new-dir-3/ [R=301,L,NE]

    # For any case insensitive directories we can try adding NO-CASE (NC)
    RewriteRule ^My-Old-Dir/$ /my-new-dir/ [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```