# Case sensitive urls in apache

Tags: linux, case-sensitive

Will any buddy help me to make my urls insensitive .. i want to make domain.com/url.ext is just like domain.com/Url.EXT

Remember

```
CheckSpelling on
```

is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021796/make-folders-in-apache-case-insensitive-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily done by using the mod_speling module, which is part of the standard apache distribution:

CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On

After restarting httpd you can access ABC as Abc or abc

Answer (score 0):

You can use RewriteMap and `int:tolower` as per the example in the `mod_rewrite` documentation

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int

Comment: If you're asking for help you should explain what you've tried (copy/paste) and what errors you're seeing

Comment: I have upload my files to server some file extension is in capital like SOMEFILE.EXT i cannot rename all files with lower case not even change all url to capital and the problem is unix has case sensitive urls but i want to make it case insensitive .. so my url 

http://domain.tld/somefile.ext should be directed to http://domain.tld/SOMEFILE.EXT and vise versa

Comment: I understand the problem. You need to explain what you've tried, what happened, what didn't happen, details of error messages, etc